# How to encode String with Java to receive identical effect as with PHP

Tags: java, php, xml, encoding, saml

I've got a PHP function which encodes strings with saml/xml as content:

```
function encodeSamlRequest($samlRequest) {
    return addslashes(rawurlencode(base64_encode(gzdeflate($samlRequest))));
}
```

I've to create Java method which can produce identical output:

```
private String encodeRequest(String samlRequest) {
    byte[] samlRequestBytes = samlRequest.getBytes();

    // gzdeflate
    Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
    compressor.deflate(samlRequestBytes);

    // base64_encode
    byte[] encodedDeflatedSamlRequest = Base64.getEncoder().encode(samlRequestBytes);

    // rawurlenccode
    String encodedSamlRequest = null;
    try {
        encodedSamlRequest = URLEncoder.encode(new String(encodedDeflatedSamlRequest), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encodedSamlRequest;
}

private byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[]{
            (byte) (value >> 24),
            (byte) (value >> 16),
            (byte) (value >> 8),
            (byte) value};
}
```

I tried to use [Deflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html), [Base64.Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html), URIEncoder and URI classes (two last without urls because my reputation < 10), but output is totally different.

Test input:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_e48eec122b20b6b83702" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-09-28T13:54:16Z" Destination="https://hetman-int.epuap.gov.pl/DracoEngine2/draco.jsf" IsPassive="false" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8085/index.jsp"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">/test12/myapp-12423534</saml:Issuer></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Expected output:

```
fVHJbsIwEP2VyPfEiRMgtUgkVHpAolIFLYdeKhMG4ioZux4H0b%2BvA6pELz3O8pZ5MyfVd1YuBt%2FiBr4GIB9d%2Bg5JXgcVGxxKo0iTRNUDSd%2FI7eJ5LUWSSuuMN43pWLRaVuwDihKgyYTYi3Q%2F3Zf5LBUs2oEjbbBiAREWiQZYIXmFPrTSbBanD7EoX7NcTgqZTd9ZtAwmNCp%2FRbXeW5Kct%2BB7hbFGn4AdlE1O5pzYji%2BdaswTnjSC4IexSD7pOAq9KCJ9hoodVUfAogURuJH00SANPbgtuLNu4G2zvskElc40qmsNeVmm5YRrPMAl8FlWz8c85NW%2Bu0vo%2F4DUrySruQ9XZYL338raOBOFyCd5Med3tPWt%2BvuN%2Bgc%3D
```

My output:

```
eJxhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCB4bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIiBJRD0iX2U0OGVlYzEyMmIyMGI2YjgzNzAyIiBWZXJzaW9uPSIyLjAiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxNy0wOS0yOFQxMzo1NDoxNloiIERlc3RpbmF0aW9uPSJodHRwczovL2hldG1hbi1pbnQuZXB1YXAuZ292LnBsL0RyYWNvRW5naW5lMi9kcmFjby5qc2YiIElzUGFzc2l2ZT0iZmFsc2UiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDg1L3N1Y2Nlc3MuanNwIj48c2FtbDpJc3N1ZXIgeG1sbnM6c2FtbD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOmFzc2VydGlvbiI%2BL3Rlc3Rwbi9Eb215nGxuYS0xNDk2MDM0NjAyOTA5PC9zYW1sOklzc3Vlcj48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3D
```

Any advices or ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share the actual code of what you tried instead of just `//implementation` ?

Comment: Added, I'm sorry!

Comment: The java impl doesn't look the same. `int deflatedSamlRequest = compressor.deflate(samlRequestBytes);` will return the compressed size of the string. However you're using that size as though it's the data you need. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html

Comment: @apokryfos You're right, thanks. But unfortunately it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I ran both those strings form a urldecoder and base64 decoder and only the 2nd one resembled XML, which is odd as it implies that the Java code is more correct than the PHP one

Comment: I found working solution here: [create-http-redirect-binding-saml-request-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484948/create-http-redirect-binding-saml-request-using-java). Thanks for your help!