# Block length does not match with its complement

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm trying to handle a redirect authentication piece for a site we have. I configured ADFS on Server2012 R2 to handle this. I set up the relying party trust with a URL in our domain that I'm sending requests from. I added an endpoint back to the specific page they're coming from.

Basically, I'm taking this stuff here: [How do I correctly prepare an 'HTTP Redirect Binding' SAML Request using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090403/how-do-i-correctly-prepare-an-http-redirect-binding-saml-request-using-c-sharp)

to try and send over a simple SAML request token.

```
        public static string SAMLRequest = @"<samlp:AuthnRequest
        xmlns:samlp=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol""
        xmlns:saml=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion""
        ID=""{0}""
        Version=""2.0""
        AssertionConsumerServiceIndex=""0""
        AttributeConsumingServiceIndex=""0"">
        <saml:Issuer>URN:xx-xx-xx</saml:Issuer>
        <samlp:NameIDPolicy
            AllowCreate = ""true""
            Format=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"" />
    </samlp:AuthnRequest>";
```

This is the template URL I'm sending over as a C# string (for the escape characters, and the string replacement on the ID value).

And here is the code I'm using to generate the request parameter that's going into my redirect URL:

```
public static string GetSAMLHttpRedirectUri(string idpUri)
{
    var saml = string.Format(SAMLRequest, Guid.NewGuid());
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saml);
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new DeflaterOutputStream(output))
        {
            zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
        var urlEncode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
        return string.Concat(idpUri, "?SAMLRequest=", urlEncode);
    }
}
```

When all is said and done, the page redirects me to the appropriate endpoint with the token base64 encoded properly. Well, sort of properly.

On the AD FS side of things, I get an error on the page and then it just stops authenticating. Looking in the event viewer of AD FS, it gives me this cryptic error:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Block length does not match with its complement.
```

I've tried fiddling with the compression and some of the properties on the request object itself, to no avail. Anyone have any ideas I could try on this bad boy?

Comment: Is there a reason you manually create saml 2.0 request?

Comment: I didn't see a library to use that would let me build the SAML request token for redirects easily. If you know of a good one, I'm all ears.

Comment: Point is, Saml 1.1 is supported in contrast to 2.0. That's why I ask why you go with 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `DeflaterOutputStream` is from SharpZipLib, `new DeflaterOutputStream(output)` will, in fact, give you a *ZLIB* output stream, that is [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt), not actually DEFLATE, from [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt). The difference is only that ZLIB adds a header and footer to DEFLATE, which you can suppress in SharpZipLib with `new DeflaterOutputStream(output, new Deflater(level: Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, noZlibHeaderOrFooter: true))`.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/05/16/system-io-compression-capabilities-kim-hamilton/ shows how to strip the ZLIB header and footer so that `DeflateStream` can be used on the remaining Deflate data.

Comment: @jnm2 omg THANK YOU. Discovering that stripping the header and checksum allows the .Net DeflateStream to work saved us days of going down the wrong path assuming the files were corrupted by an evil open source java compression library.